# mdadm --scan --examine --config - nonexisting arrays

Tags: raid, mdadm

I came across weird situation where after running

```
mdadm --examine --scan --config=mdadm.conf >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

I get to see ARRAYS that are not yet created 11-15. Those are going to be RAID0 ARRAYS above duos of already existing arrays like md1+2, md3+4 etc. They were existing before, but i stopped and removed all arrays and also cleaned GPT tables of all disks by sgdisk -Z and started from scratch, since there was previously HW raid and it was messing with new MDADM SW raid - i decided for full celanup first.

I dont understand form where he takes those 11-15 ARRAYS. Iam about to assemble them, but now i dont see reason why SCAN finds  them. Also, before i manually assembled RAID md1-10, scan found only md1-10, after assemble was done, it found also md11-15 as its somehow still remembers that it was there, even after removal of ARRAYS and wipe of GPT tables.

Any ideas why is this happening? Should i just continue, create my md11-15 again to be safe, then filesystem and call it done? I dont see mentions of md11-15 anywhere on the system, but still scans finds them, so iam sure iam missing some step in my full cleanup from previous RAID config (thought sgdisk would be enough, dont want to run dd)

```
# This configuration was auto-generated on Fri, 13 Jul 2018 08:01:55 +0000 by mkconf
ARRAY /dev/md/2  metadata=1.2 UUID=4993a3d5:f0a39e85:f8104370:aed5e951 name=vod0-iva:2
ARRAY /dev/md/3  metadata=1.2 UUID=40de46c2:70c6e63f:e9576997:285c2ff3 name=vod0-iva:3
ARRAY /dev/md/4  metadata=1.2 UUID=d18b1263:fb902e8b:730f522a:db993f40 name=vod0-iva:4
ARRAY /dev/md/5  metadata=1.2 UUID=5b6db0c0:53cb2714:4a982ac4:9a837cca name=vod0-iva:5
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=1fa709ac:47d4e831:49b29e7a:380a198a name=vod0-iva:1
ARRAY /dev/md/6  metadata=1.2 UUID=183429d2:fb95b326:3016ab5c:6cd80d2f name=vod0-iva:6
ARRAY /dev/md/7  metadata=1.2 UUID=36b01bb6:97a0095f:9e7a4d61:994e9577 name=vod0-iva:7
ARRAY /dev/md/8  metadata=1.2 UUID=6918a7f7:e77b8f46:38cd4ff6:e3e16740 name=vod0-iva:8
ARRAY /dev/md/10  metadata=1.2 UUID=5306e805:a8cf4af3:53b32a3a:445e277d name=vod0-iva:10
ARRAY /dev/md/9  metadata=1.2 UUID=bc7a0857:84f133c4:453dcc65:1ae11abe name=vod0-iva:9
ARRAY /dev/md/12  metadata=1.2 UUID=8058a306:82349197:eedf57a2:0fb80379 name=vod0-iva:12
ARRAY /dev/md/11  metadata=1.2 UUID=7457d40b:43c54eeb:e0f80116:4a61d704 name=vod0-iva:11
ARRAY /dev/md/13  metadata=1.2 UUID=948fafe9:bb978a3d:cd1798fc:665e5fd3 name=vod0-iva:13
ARRAY /dev/md/14  metadata=1.2 UUID=d92e3941:97e09b3e:eefd835c:1b2fa1d6 name=vod0-iva:14
ARRAY /dev/md/15  metadata=1.2 UUID=85845557:7d9e00b5:a1a0d25b:fe24ad34 name=vod0-iva:15

root@vod0-iva:~# mdadm --examine /dev/md
md/   md1   md10  md2   md3   md4   md5   md6   md7   md8   md9   
root@vod0-iva:~# mdadm --examine /dev/md/
1   10  2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   


root@vod0-iva:/dev# cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  233832448 sda
   8        1       9216 sda1
   8        2  233821167 sda2
   8       16 2930266584 sdb
   8       32 2930266584 sdc
**
**
  68      224 2930266584 sdca
  68      240 2930266584 sdcb
  69       16 2930266584 sdcd
  69       32 2930266584 sdce
  67      128 3907018584 sdbe
  69        0 2930266584 sdcc
  69       48 2930266584 sdcf
  67       64 3907018584 sdba
  69       64 2930266584 sdcg
  11        0    1048575 sr0
 253        0  104857600 dm-0
   9        2 11720540160 md2
   9        3 11720540160 md3
   9        4 11720540160 md4
   9        5 11720540160 md5
   9        1 11720540160 md1
   9        6 11720540160 md6
   9        7 11720540160 md7
   9        8 11720540160 md8
   9       10 11720540160 md10
   9        9 11720540160 md9

root@vod0-iva:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md9 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdax[0] sdbc[5] sdbb[4] sdba[3] sdaz[2] sday[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md10 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdbd[0] sdbi[5] sdbh[4] sdbg[3] sdbf[2] sdbe[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md8 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdar[0] sdaw[5] sdav[4] sdau[3] sdat[2] sdas[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md7 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdal[0] sdaq[5] sdap[4] sdao[3] sdan[2] sdam[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md6 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdaf[0] sdak[5] sdaj[4] sdai[3] sdah[2] sdag[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdb[0] sdg[5] sdf[4] sde[3] sdd[2] sdc[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md5 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdz[0] sdae[5] sdad[4] sdac[3] sdab[2] sdaa[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md4 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdt[0] sdy[5] sdx[4] sdw[3] sdv[2] sdu[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md3 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdn[0] sds[5] sdr[4] sdq[3] sdp[2] sdo[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md2 : active (auto-read-only) raid6 sdh[0] sdm[5] sdl[4] sdk[3] sdj[2] sdi[1]
      11720540160 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [6/6] [UUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk


root@vod0-iva:~# mdadm --examine /dev/md1
/dev/md1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 7457d40b:43c54eeb:e0f80116:4a61d704
           Name : vod0-iva:11  (local to host vod0-iva)
  Creation Time : Mon Feb 25 13:02:38 2019
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 23440818176 (11177.45 GiB 12001.70 GB)
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 3363cbc0:5a24a185:6bd4ed73:ab3e9429

    Update Time : Mon Feb 25 13:02:38 2019
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 5f45a1f6 - correct
         Events : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

root@vod0-iva:~# mdadm --examine /dev/md11
mdadm: cannot open /dev/md11: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems i needed to zero superblock of md1-10 arrays in order to be able to ADD them into  higher RAID0 again, It seems strange to me since i stopped, removed md's and sgdisk -Z all disks and then created md1-10 again, they undergo initialization and all - everything looked as making whole new arrays, just same names. So i wonder where the metadata saying that md1-10 are part of another (already stoped and removed) ARRAYS - which did not exist in any of outputs above - were stored.

--scan obviously found them in zero-block of md1-10, but how the data got into zero-block table, after second intialization, after wipe, simply said into the whole new, not yet used or added anywere md1-10 arrays...mystery

```
root@vod0-iva:/dev# mdadm --create /dev/md11 -v --raid-devices=2 --level=0 /dev/md1 /dev/md2
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: /dev/md1 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=2 ctime=Mon Feb 25 13:02:38 2019
mdadm: /dev/md2 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid0 devices=2 ctime=Mon Feb 25 13:02:38 2019

root@vod0-iva:/dev# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/md1
root@vod0-iva:/dev# mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/md2

root@vod0-iva:/dev# mdadm --create /dev/md11 -v --raid-devices=2 --level=0 /dev/md1 /dev/md2
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md11 started.
```